# PHP frameworks : MVC..and what else?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, architecture, frameworks

I was just wondering (sake of knowledge) if  "PHP-framework" concepts is strictly binded and depending upon the "MVC" concept.What I mean is: there's any php framework not relying on the MVC architecture??

At [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework)

```
Most web application frameworks are based on the MVC pattern.
```

thanks.Most not all =)

Luca

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary for a PHP framework to use the MVC paradigm.

However, it is very useful so it often used.

Comment: thanks.I find the MVC really useful as well =) just wanted to know any no-MVC php framework

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps off topic: Hierarchical Model-View-Controller pattern is an interesting variant of MVC and is supported in frameworks such as [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) (directly) and CodeIgnitor ([indirectly](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home))

Answer (score 0):

The MVC architecture is not limited to php and there many alternative. I had a similar question recently:

[What are the alternatives to MVC architecture for web development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931085/what-are-the-alternatives-to-mvc-architecture-for-web-development)

Comment: I didnt mean "MVC" architecture limited to PHP but I wonder if PHP frameworks are limited to MVC

Comment: No like you can see on my link there are many other frameworks proposed